# How to create a bash screen with multiple commands

Tags: bash, shell, gnu-screen

I´m new on the linux screen command but I know that you can create a new detached named screen executing a command `screen -dmS SCREEN_NAME command`
But is there a way to create a new detached screen executing two commands?
like `screen -dmS SCREEN_NAME cd PATH java -jar *.jar`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
screen -dmS SCREEN_NAME bash -c 'command1...; command2 ...'
```